# How to create a measure in power bi that counts yes and no values based on a country

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization

I am new to power bi, i am trying to use "state cards" by okviz to create multiple dynamic cards.

i have an example of the following data structure: table 1

```
Country  | Answer
Amercica | Yes
America  | NO
America  | YES
America  | Yes
Brazil   | NO
Brazil   | NO
Brazil   | NO
Brazil   | NO
Brazil   | yes
```

how do i create a measure in power bi that counts the yes and no columns per country and gives me the following output

```
Country | Answer |count
America |Yes     |3
America |No      |1
Brazil  |Yes     |1
Brazil  |No      |4
```

Answer (score 1):

First standardize the Answer column. This is not necessary but I don't like all those different yes words.

[image]

You don't need a measure to achieve this. You can drag a column and chose the count option. But if you really need a measure use the following expression:

```
Answer Count = COUNT( 'Table'[Answer] )
```

[image]

Both ways you obtain the same result.